# Comparing for a given value in a list of objects - java 8

Tags: java, java-8, stream

I have list of Objects

```
class Product{

  String productName;
  int mfgYear;
  int expYear;
} 


int testYear = 2019;
List<Product> productList = getProductList();
```

I have list of products here.

Have to iterate each one of the Product from the list and get the `List<String> productName` that lies in the range between mfgYear &  expYear for a given 2019(testYear).

```
For example, 
mfgYear <= 2019 <= expYear
```

How can I write this in java 8 streams.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as following:

```
int givenYear = 2019;

List<String> productNames = 
                  products.stream()
                          .filter(p -> p.mfgYear <= givenYear && givenYear <= p.expYear)
                          .map(Product::name)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

// It would be more clean if you can define a boolean function inside your product class

class Product {
// your code as it is
boolean hasValidRangeGiven(int testYear) {
       return mfgDate <= testYear && testYear <= expYear:
}

List<String> productNames = products.stream()
                                    .filter(p -> p.hasValidRange(givenYear))
                                    .map(Product::name)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> process(List<Product> productList) {
    return productList.stream()
            .filter(this::isWithinRange)
            .map(Product::getProductName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

boolean isWithinRange(Product product) {
    return product.mfgYear <= 2019 && product.expYear <= 2019;
}

static class Product {

    String productName;
    int mfgYear;
    int expYear;

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }
}
```

**filter()** will pass any item for which the lambda expression (or method reference in this case) return true. **map()** will convert the value passing the item to the method reference and create a stream of whatever type it returns. We pass the name getter in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..Is there a way to pass a testYear variable from isWithinRange as my comparing year will change between every check..